# Kotlin for loop not printing in Kotlin Script

Tags: loops, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm playing with the for loop, in Kotlin Script (*.kts file) I have this in the file:

```
for (i in 1..5) print("$i, ")
```

I did think it would print the number 1 through 5 separated by commas in one line like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
```

But instead I don't get any output on the command line. I'm running this on a Mac via

```
kotlin ranges.kts
```

If I put anything behind this single for loop, like a seperate println() or if I replace the print in the loop with println, it works and gives me output.

I don't get this behaviour. Can anyone explain this to me?

**Edit1:**
Versions:
kotlin: 1.3.71
MacOS 10.15.4 (Catalina)

Comment: Well for me it does prints: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ##scratch##generated##kotlin.Unit`

Comment: @AnimeshSahu on which platform and version of os & kotlin?

Comment: Kotlin 1.3.72 @ Windows 10 1909. Maybe it happened because i was using REPL in running the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `for` loop and everything to do with `print`. It works if you add `System.out.flush()` at the end of the script. By default, writes to `System.out` (which `print` uses under the hood) don't always flush, and its likely that the Kotlin script runner isn't flushing the standard output stream before exiting.

This is also why using `println` works, as you noted -- if you look at the [implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#l540) of `println` in PrintStream, you'll see that it does flush its internal text and character output streams.

I created issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38263.

Comment: In addition: `prinln()` calls are far more common than `print()`, for this reason and others.  If you want to print several things you can format them first — e.g. `println((1..5).joinToString())`.